# Using Strftime to format DateTime

Tags: c++, strftime

I am working on a function to format the input timestamp to the input format.

```
std::string 1stformat = "dd - MM - yyyy HH 'Hours' mm 'Minutes' ss 'Seconds' SSS 'Miliseconds –' a '– Time Zone: ' Z '-' zzzz";//will not print anything
std::string 2ndformat = "'This took about' h 'minutes and' s 'seconds.'";//will print out
```

After format

```
char date_string[100];
strftime(date_string, 50, format.c_str(), curr_tm);
```

My problem is that there will be sometimes the input format too long which made the buffer `date_string` not enough to content. I am just getting into C++ for the past 3 weeks so I don't have much ex about this.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `strftime()` doesn't act like `snprintf()` where it returns the number of characters that would be written to the destination if it was long enough. You have to check its return value and allocate a bigger string if needed and try again and repeat until it's long enough.

Comment: C++20 will have [std::chrono::format()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/format)... if your're using a recent enough compiler, that might be available already.

Comment: Unfortunate that I am just allowed to use C++14

Comment: I can check the length of my `format` string but I can't define `char date_string[format.length];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wrapper for `strftime()` that grows a buffer as needed until it's big enough to fit the desired time string:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

std::string safe_strftime(const char *fmt, const std::tm *t) {
  std::size_t len = 10; // Adjust initial length as desired. Maybe based on the length of fmt?
  auto buff = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
  while (std::strftime(buff.get(), len, fmt, t) == 0) {
    len *= 2;
    buff = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
  }
  return std::string{buff.get()};
}

int main() {
  std::time_t now;
  std::time(&now);
  std::cout << safe_strftime("The date is %Y-%m-%d", std::localtime(&now))
            << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can't understand. But thanks in advanced.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm The key is that `strftime()` returns 0 if the supplied destination buffer isn't big enough to hold the entire formatted string. So keep calling it with a bigger and bigger buffer until it does fit. (I used an initial size of 10 to demonstrate having to grow it; you'll likely want to start with a larger number as per the comment).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the interface to `std::strftime()` is less helpful than that of `std::snprintf()` in that it returns 0 if the buffer is too small, rather than the number of characters that would be written.  We need to increase the buffer size heuristically and retry, perhaps like this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
    
std::string time_to_string(const char *format, const std::tm* time)
{
    // first try with an on-stack buffer (fast path)
    char buf[200];
    auto written = std::strftime(buf, sizeof buf, format, time);
    if (written > 0) {
        return buf;
    }

    // now, iterate with an allocated buffer
    auto len = sizeof buf;
    std::vector<char> v;
    do {
        v.resize(len *= 2);
        written = std::strftime(v.data(), v.size(), format, time);
    } while (written == 0);

    return {v.data(), written};
}
```

---

Alternatively, instead of `std::strftime()`, we can use `std::put_time()` to write to an output stream, which will extend its storage as necessary:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string time_to_string(const char *format, const std::tm* time)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::put_time(time, format);
    return os.str();
}
```

As well as being simpler, the C++ approach allows us to write using a specific (non-default) locale, by adding a call to `os.imbue()` before streaming the date.